# Tweak loading times of Jersey over AppEngine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jersey, java-ws

my application service is not able to start or respond to even warmup requests as the time taken by Jersey to scan the libraries is inordinate.

I have created application and hardcoded all the paths of the Resources for jersey.

```
<servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
<init-param>
<param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
<param-value>com.livily.rest.JerseyApplication</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Jersey Application has all the classes

```
public Set<Class<?>> getClasses()
{
Set<Class<?>> s = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
s.add(com.livily.rest.visitor.UserRatingUtil.class);
}
```

However, jersey is scanning for lot of providers

```
Mar 8, 2013 3:39:40 PM com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderServices getServiceClasses
CONFIG:     Provider found: class com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.parameter.multivalued.StringReaderProviders$StringConstructor
```

It is doing it about 50-100 times and then

```
Mar 8, 2013 3:39:41 PM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.modelapi.annotation.IntrospectionModeller createResource
FINEST: A new abstract resource created by IntrospectionModeler: AbstractResource("/current-status", - CurrentStatus: 1 constructors, 0 fields, 0 setter methods, 1 res methods, 0 subres methods, 0 subres locators )
```

for each one

The time taken in total is about 4-10 secs and appengine does not like this as it expects to wrap up the loading quickly; otherwise it starts giving weird 500 errors (for even static files).

I am stumped; any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Not an answer, but I had similar load time issues with jersey and I moved to RestExpress (https://github.com/RestExpress/RestExpress), which doesn't have any of the J2EE weight.

Comment: Cloudpre - that's not a valid comment

Comment: Lipis - I moved to restexpress and to my surprise, it was actually slower in load time. I still get deadline exceptions. What is the best way to figure out what is taking lot of startup time? I changed logger level to all and find lot of output. Is this the best way?

Comment: what other libraries are you using?

Comment: appengine, apps-marketplace, appengine-api-labs, guava, jackson-mapper, resteasy, joda-time-1.6, jsoup, commons-lang, objectify (about 20 registrations), jackson-core, openid4java, gson, mustache-compiler, scannotation, jsr107cache, commons-logging, asm. Nothing unusual. I use 1.7.5 and jar all the classes under WEB-INF.

Comment: Moving to F4 is one workaround for this mid-size app.

Answer (score 1):

I use the packages property to name which packages should be scanned as follows...

```
    <init-param>
         <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
         <param-value>com.foo.myproviders</param-value>
    </init-param>
```

Comment: Jaytee - packages scanning are in fact slower than explicit defining the classes in the JaxRS Application.

Comment: how can you explicit define the classes in JaxRS Application? I thought the package scanning was the only possibility

Answer (score 1):

Set **`jersey.config.disableAutoDiscovery`**. See [Configuration Properties](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/appendix-properties.html) for details.

```xml
<init-param>
    <param-name>jersey.config.disableAutoDiscovery</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
```